# How to make changes while viewing a diff in bzr explorer?

Tags: bazaar, diff

`bzr explorer` is the GUI tool for Bazaar (`bzr`). It can show diffs pretty nicely, but I can't figure out a way to make changes in the diff viewer. Other basic functions would be the ability to copy entire chunks of differences from the base version to the working copy. I'm wondering if the function exists and I just cannot find it, or maybe the function doesn't exist at all.

If this is not possible within `bzr explorer`, then I'd like to know how I can configure Bazaar to view (and hopefully edit) differences in `gvimdiff`. At the moment when I want to do this, I first dump the original version of a file with `bzr cat -r123 file > file.r123` and run `gvimdiff` in a separate step, which is tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

`bzr diff --using gvimdiff [file]`

Or open the "User Configuration" menu of bzr explorer, and set gvimdiff as an external diff application ; this will be offered at the top of the built in diff.

My qbzr.conf reads :

```
[DEFAULT]
config_window_size = 651x422
diff_window_size = 780x580
default_diff = gvimdiff
[EXTDIFF]
gvimdiff = gvimdiff
```

I think the difficulty with the config is that the first column is the name of the diff option ; the second is the command (and accepts certain keyword expansion sequences as well).

Comment: The `--using` helps! There's no way to edit with the built in diff tool? Also, in the "User Configuration" I tried to add it, when I press OK the window closes without an error message, but actually does not save what I added, so when I go back to "User Configuration" it doesn't have my setting. Maybe I can set this manually in `bazaar.conf`? Do you know how?